# Plot Shapefile with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I want to create a facet with nine (in this example only three) maps in one plot. I have managed to plot almost ideally one map when I `subset` from the original `shapefile`. However, when I try to plot them all at once it is not possible.

The plot needs to have the same legend (discrete numbers as values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`) even when some of the maps only has values from `1` to `4`.

In addition, when for one of the polygons there is missing data, it should be plotted in gray, with legend `NA value`.

An example of the output from the code below is at the bottom. An example data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LmEGQt8yzbPeKzebqWng_Myybx2xEiQF?usp=sharing).

```
path <- '~path'
muniCluster <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn=path, layer="data")

class(muniCluster)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"


ilum <- subset(muniCluster, CLUSTER == "CLUS_ILUM")
ilum$VALUES <- as.integer(ilum$VALUES)

ilum_df <- fortify(ilum)
ilum_tidy <- tidy(ilum)

class(ilum_df)
class(ilum_tidy)

# Recategorizes data as required for plotting
ilum$id <- row.names(ilum)
ilum_tidy <- left_join(ilum_tidy, ilum@data)
ilum_tidy$VALUES <- as.factor(ilum_tidy$VALUES)

ilum_map_v2 <- ggplot(ilum_tidy, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = VALUES)) +
     geom_polygon(color = "black", size = 0.1) +
     labs(title = "Light cluster") +
     scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) 

ilum_map_final_v2 <- ilum_map_v2 + coord_map() 

print(ilum_map_final_v2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays is probably easier to use the `sf`package to plot the type of maps you want. You can see some examples here https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html

I adapted an example from there, which shows how to use `ggplot2` and its `facet_wrap` function to create a map for each level of a given variable.

Some steps shown here may not be necessary if you already have, for example, a variable with certain amount of levels which you which to facet.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(classInt)
library(viridis)

# Read example shapefile from sf package
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# subset columns of interest as well as geometry column
# create BIR in which the variables BIR74, BIR79, NWBIR79
# become different levels of it
nc2 <- nc %>% select(BIR74, BIR79, NWBIR79, geometry) %>% gather(VAR, BIR, -geometry)

# HEre i just wanted to create 5 categories for the BIR variable
ints <- classIntervals(nc2$BIR, n = 5, style = "jenks")
nc2 <- nc2 %>% mutate(BIR_cat = cut(BIR, ints$brks, dig.lab=10)) 

# I just changed the levels's labels to match the output you are looking for
nc2 <- nc2 %>% mutate(values = ifelse(BIR_cat == "(3,1946]", "1", 
                                ifelse(BIR_cat == "(1946,4706]", "2", 
                                 ifelse(BIR_cat == "(4706,9087]", "3",
                                  ifelse(BIR_cat == "(9087,16184]", "4",
                                    ifelse(BIR_cat == "(16184,30757]", "5", NA))))))

# Map the spatial data
ggplot() +
 geom_sf(data = nc2, aes(fill = values)) +
 facet_wrap(~VAR, ncol = 1) +
 scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, but how is the structure of the file `nc.shp`? I am asking this to fully replicate your answer with the data I have.

Comment: Hey, the example I posted is completely reproducible, if you install and load the required packages you can check the structure of `nc.shp`.  And as I said, I would recommend using the `sf` package to deal with spatial data in R. Anyway, you could just use `facet_wrap()` in your code to create multiple plots, one for each level of the variable you may be interested. I would also recommend reading [this](https://gist.github.com/hadley/270442#:~:text=A%20reproducible%20example%20allows%20someone,description%20of%20your%20R%20environment.&text=Run%20dput(mtcars)%20in%20R,Copy%20the%20output).